# Symfony 2.8 functional testing - add values to the session array

Tags: php, symfony, session, phpunit

I'm having a controller which reads an integer from the session array in this manner:

```
if ($session->has('administration'))
{
     $id = $session->get('entity_id');
     return $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:SomeEntity')->find($id);
}
```

Currently I'm writing tests for this controller action but I can't find how to inject this integer in the sessions array. I tried the following:

```
$this->client = $this->makeClient(true);

$this->client->getContainer()->set('session.storage.options.entity_id', 12);
```

This, however doesn't work and seems to just ignore the value. Therefore, my question is how to store values in the session array in a functional test environment? (note: I'm using the Liip test bundle)

**Extra configs that may have impact**

```
// config_test.yml
liip_functional_test:
cache_sqlite_db: true
authentication:
    username: "%test.username%"
    password: "%test.password%"

framework:
    test: ~
    session:
       storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
    profiler:
       collect: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony as a Mock of the session for tests, as defined [here in the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_testing.html)

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\MockFileSessionStorage;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

$session = new Session(new MockFileSessionStorage());
$session->set('entity_id', 12);
```

Comment: Nope. I already tried this `$session->set('entity_id', 12);` but it is still empty. This is probably the case because somehow this new session needs to be connected to the client.

Comment: Even if I try `$this->client->getContainer()->set('session', $session);` after that, it is still empty.